# .focus() and native keyboard isn't activating

Tags: android, cordova, sapui5

I have an issue with "focus()" on an input field in an SAPUI5 web app within Cordova.

Here is the code I use.

```
sap.ui.getCore().byId("inputQuant").focus()
```

I even tried the following

```
setTimeout(function() { sap.ui.getCore().byId("inputQuant").focus() },3000);
```

and

```
jQuery.sap.delayedCall(0, this, function() {
                      sap.ui.getCore().byId("inputQuant").focus();});
```

but the native Android Keyboard isn't "engaging". The input is focused, by the JQuery standards, but not from the device's point of view.

Is there a way to manipulate this ?

What I'm trying to do is: From an existing screen, I call a function to open a dialog. After the dialog opens, I should focus the input field and pop up the device's keyboard.

Here is how I create the dialog:

```
function getInputDialog(objParameters){
        title       = objParameters.title;
        description = objParameters.description;
        contentText = objParameters.contentText;
        to          = objParameters.to;
        context     = objParameters.context;
        model       = objParameters.model;
        value       = objParameters.value;

        var app = sap.ui.getCore().byId("App--app");
        var myDialog = sap.ui.getCore().byId('inputDialog');
        if(myDialog == undefined){
            var xml = '' +
        '<Dialog id="inputDialog" xmlns="sap.m" title="{inputDialogModel>/title}">                                  ' +
        '   <content>                                                                                               ' +
        '   <FlexBox alignItems="Center" justifyContent="Center">                                                   ' +
        '       <Label text="{inputDialogModel>/contentText}" />                                                    ' +
        '   </FlexBox>                                                                                              ' +
        '   <FlexBox alignItems="Center" justifyContent="Center">                                                   ' +
        '       <Input  id="inputQuant" type="Number" width="100%"                                                  ' +
        '               description="{inputDialogModel>/description}" value="1"/>                                   ' +
        '   </FlexBox>                                                                                              ' +
        '   </content>                                                                                              ' +
        '   <buttons>                                                                                               ' +
        '       <Button text="{inputDialogModel>/actionText2}" press="closeDialog2"/>                               ' +
        '       <Button text="{inputDialogModel>/actionText1}" press="closeDialog1"/>                               ' +
        '   </buttons>                                                                                              ' +
        '</Dialog>                                                                                                  ';
        // create some dummy JSON data and create a Model from it
        var data = {
            title:          title, //"Introduceti o cantitate",
            description:    description, //"buc",
            contentText:    contentText, //"Some Fragment Content",
            actionText1:    "Confirma",
            actionValue1:   to, //
            actionText2:    "Renunta",
            model:          model
        };

        // create a dummy Controller for the action in the Dialog
        var oDummyController = {
            onAfterRendering: function(){
                setTimeout(function() { sap.ui.getCore().byId("inputQuant").focus() },2000);
                jQuery.sap.delayedCall(0, this, function() {
                      sap.ui.getCore().byId("inputQuant").focus();});
            },
            onBeforeShow: function(){
            setTimeout(function() { sap.ui.getCore().byId("inputQuant").focus() },2000);
            jQuery.sap.delayedCall(0, this, function() {
                  sap.ui.getCore().byId("inputQuant").focus();});
        },
            closeDialog2: function(){
                myDialog.close();
            },
            closeDialog1: function(){
                    //Update model with new value for quant
                    context.getModel(model).updateBindings();
                    myDialog.close();
                    app.to(to);
                } else {
                    var oModeli18n = new sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel({
                        bundleUrl: "i18n/i18n.properties"
                        });
                    sap.m.MessageToast.show(oModeli18n.getProperty("Pop_up_add_quantity"));
                }
            }
        };

        // instantiate the Fragment if not done yet
                myDialog = sap.ui.xmlfragment({fragmentContent:xml}, oDummyController);

                var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
                oModel.setData(data);
                myDialog.setModel(oModel, "inputDialogModel");
            }
        sap.ui.getCore().byId("inputQuant").setValue(value);
        sap.ui.getCore().byId("inputQuant").focus();
        return myDialog;
    }
```

If I manually press the input, I see the keyboard, but when I use coding, it doesn't trigger.

Thank you in advance,
Nep.

Comment: I've tried the above codes on an existing and normal view.

Comment: In the :
onBeforeShow
onAfterRendering
functions of the page. 
Ergo I think I might have a problem in my code. Why I say that, because when I add a break-point in one of those 2 functions of the XML fragment, it doesn't stop. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Focus should have worked! Nevertheless Try this> **autofocus**

```
   <Input  id="inputQuant" type="Number" width="100%" autofocus
description="{inputDialogModel>/description}" value="1"/>
```

Comment: Nope, that didn't work either :(
Any other ideas regarding "how" should I do it ?

Comment: oh, I have nothing in mind right now. Will keep you posted if I find something